# Facebook "Reply to this email to message" does not seem to actually send message

Tags: facebook

Sometimes when I am not logged on Facebook and my friend Joe sends me a message, it is sent to my email (Gmail), with a footer saying:

> Reply to this email to message Joe

When I reply to the email it, Joe does not seem to receive that reply, though.

Is there any reason why it would not work? Configuration? Any kind of usage limit?

The `To:` field is:

`Message Email Reply <m+30vphcxm000000bgz9hk00003nxhyki5nld6b06tbril24iw2n2@reply.facebook.com>`

Comment: @pnuts: Thanks for the feedback, I added the info. I am really talking about private messages (1-to-1), not wall posts.

Comment: @pnuts: I actually changed a number of letters into other letters, and a number of digits into other digits. The message shows up normally in my Gmail "Sent" folder, but does not show up in my Facebook conversation with this person.

Comment: @pnuts Joe had not seen my message when logging into Facebook, even 8 hours afterwards.